# Cancel Changes to Datagridview Bound to Custom Class

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been researching for hours on this topic and can't seem to get to a solution or reasonable explanation as why it doesn't work. I've found similar posts but none address what I'm looking for. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983194/how-to-cancel-changes-made-through-databinding) post helped me the most as far as understanding how it works. I was even able to successfully test this using a TextBox. Problem is I'd like this feature for my DataGridview. I'd like to make changes in the DataGridView but not have the List updated until clicking like an "Ok" button. I've been using this test setup:

Simple class:

```
public class Person
{
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public int Height { get; set; }

  public Animal(int age, int height)
  {
     Age = age;
     Height = height;
  }
}
```

I setup the databinding as usual. Snippet from my Form constructor:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  People = new List<Person>();
  personBindingSource.DataSource = People;
  personBindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = personBindingSource;
  dataGridView1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.Never;
 }
```

I edit the cell with a value and then have a button that calls the Binding.WriteValue(). The underlying datasource keeps getting automatically updated with the cell changes (Behaving like OnValidation even though I've made it Never literally everywhere I can think of). Is there something I'm missing or am I going to have to manually implement this?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460284/how-to-roll-back-changes-in-gridview-in-case-of-incorrect-input

Comment: @rob I did come across that. The problem is that CancelEdit only applies to the current edit operation. I'm not looking necessarily for a way to edit each edit operation as it happens. More so I just need the datagridview to act like my text box example. I can edit the textbox as many times as I want but the values won't propagate until I do the WriteValue(). Thank you for your comment though

Answer (score 0):

So I guess there isn't an out of the box way to accomplish what I'm looking for. I decided to implement something myself that's working for me. Basically it's the [memento pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern) with syntax similar to what's available for DataTable (namely DataTable::RejectChanges()). I created a container for a generic list as such:

```
public class ApplyCancelList<T>
{
    List<T> snapshot = null;

    public List<T> List { get; private set; }

    public ApplyCancelList()
    {
        List = new List<T>();
    }

    public void CreateMemento()
    {
        snapshot = new List<T>(List);
    }

    public void RejectChanges()
    {
        List = new List<T>(snapshot);
    }
}
```

On each form load I create a memento. If Apply is called snapshot gets updated to the accepted list. If Cancel is called I restore the snapshot. The Datagridview gets updated when I reset the datasource of the binding source. I'm not sure how elegant/efficient this solution is but it's giving me the behavior I want. If anyone sees anywhere I can improve don't hesitate to comment.